# Error: The request for procedure 'ViewName' failed because 'ViewName' is a view object

Tags: vb6, adodb

Looking for help with a random error. This code has not been changed in years and runs almost without error. Just sometimes it causes and error, "The request for procedure '*ViewName*' failed because '*ViewName*' is a view object." I am wondering if adding a CommandTypeEnum would prevent the error, and if so, which enum is used for a view, **adCmdTableDirect**?

```
With ADOConn
    .ConnectionString = myConnectionString
    .Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .Open "myView", ADOConn
        ...
```

Comment: Possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649561/mssqlsm-2008-odd-login-failed-on-select-statement

Comment: I tried that one, but it didn't apply.